# C - invalid conversion from int* to int

Tags: c, stack, queue, structure

```
Line 20| Col 15 [Error] invalid conversion from 'ElemArr* {aka int*}' to 'ElemArr {aka int}' [-fpermissive]
```

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure why. I'm a student and while studying this I encountered this specific problem when trying to engage in the 'circular array' concept. Thanks! I've tried changing ElemArr e[MAX] to int elem[MAX] and going through it there, but it still doesn't work!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5

typedef int ElemArr;

typedef struct{
    ElemArr E[MAX];
    int top;
    int back;
}Queue;

void initQueue(Queue *Q);
void Enqueue(Queue *Q, ElemArr E);

int main(){
    Queue q;
    ElemArr e[MAX] = {4, 21, 65, 12, 17};
    initQueue(&q);
    Enqueue(&q, e);
    return 0;
}

void initQueue(Queue *Q){
    Q->top = 1;
    Q->back = 0;
    printf("Queue is initialized");
}

void Enqueue(Queue *Q, ElemArr E){
    if((Q->back+2) % MAX != Q->top){
        Q->back = (Q->back+1) % MAX;
        Q->E[Q->back] = E;
        printf("Enqueue done");
    }
}

void Dequque(Queue *Q){
    if((Q->back+1) % MAX != Q->top){
        Q->top = (Q->top+1) % MAX;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second parameter to `Eneueue()` is a single `ElemArr`, but you're trying to pass `e`, which is an array of `ElemArr`.

Comment: You need to call `Enqueue` in a loop, adding each element of the array to the queue.

Comment: @WhozCraig That won't work, he wants an array of 5 elements.

Comment: Yeah, i see that. More fuel for not hiding simple types in aliases. `ElemArr` is anything-but an actual array, or pointer for that matter. retracted.

Comment: @Saberton Perchance, what does your code look like if/when you removed the needless type alias `ElemArr` and just use `int` ? Is it clear *then* what the problem is ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I'm just using that because that's the type of obfuscation and needlessness my professor performs when she gives us exams. Thank you, and I apologize for the easy question considering it's been thumbed down once.

Comment: When you initialize the queue, it would be better to set both `top` and `back` to `0`, this would simplify your other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Enqueue` function takes just one `ElemArr` value, but you're trying to pass a whole array. You need to call it separately for each element. Change

```
Enqueue(&q, e);
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    Enqueue(&q, e[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Enqueue(&q, e);`, `e` is of type `int*` but you're passing it as an `int` variable to `void Enqueue(Queue *Q, ElemArr E);` function.

You should pass a variable of type `int` to the second argument of `Enqueue` function.